# Extract value from a list of key-value pairs using grep

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds

I have a string containing a list of key-value pairs like this: "a:1,b:2,c:3". I would like to extract a value for a specified key so that e.g. I would get "1" for "a". I was planning to do it with a regex like this:

```
'(?<=(^|,)$KEY:)^,*'
```

but it seems grep doesn't support lookarounds. (I'm not even sure this regex works correctly.) Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -oP "(?:^|,)$KEY:\K[^,]+"
```

The `-o` option outputs matches. `-P` enables PCRE engine. The double quotes are necessary for string interpolation so that `$KEY` could be interpolated.

The pattern matches:

- `(?:^|,)` - start of string or comma
- `$KEY` - the `KEY` variable
- `:` - colon
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the whole text matched so far
- `[^,]+` - 1+ chars other than `,`

Comment: Only if the implementation of grep supports `-P`.  AFAIK, that's only GNU grep, and even then, only if that option was enabled when it was compiled.

Comment: Also, you should mention that `$KEY` needs to be written as regexp, not as simple string.

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple. You don't need all this look-a-whatever stuff, just do a simple string comparison of the field you want and then print the other field you want with awk:

```
$ awk -v key="a" -v RS=',' -F':' '$1==key{print $2}' <<< "a:1,b:2,c:3,"
1
```

That awk script will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box. How you pass the string to awk will be shell-dependent the `<<<` is a bash-ism but you can use this instead:

```
$ echo "a:1,b:2,c:3," | awk -v key="a" -v RS=',' -F':' '$1==key{print $2}'
1
```

or do other things depending if the string you want parsed is stored in a variable or a file or....

Comment: Brilliant! This worked for me with similar requirements to the OP.

Comment: TIL what bash-ism is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read` with an `IFS` with colon and comma as field separators like this:

```
IFS=':,' read -ra arr <<< "a:1,b:2,c:3"
```

This will give you this array:

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="1" [2]="b" [3]="2" [4]="c" [5]="3")
```

if you want to list key-value pairs then use:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2)); do echo "${arr[i]} => ${arr[i+1]}"; done
```

```
a => 1
b => 2
c => 3
```

---

To be able to fetch a single value for a given key, you may use this `sed`:

```
k=a; sed -E "s/(^|.*,)$k:([^,]*).*/\2/" <<< "a:1,b:2,c:3"
1

k=b; sed -E "s/(^|.*,)$k:([^,]*).*/\2/" <<< "a:1,b:2,c:3"
2

k=c; sed -E "s/(^|.*,)$k:([^,]*).*/\2/" <<< "a:1,b:2,c:3"
3
```

Comment: You should mention that array support isn't a POSIX Shell feature, so isn't necessarily available in the target environment.