# GREP Regex not working properly, but my regex is correct

Tags: regex, grep

Hopefully this is a simple mistake I am making, I am fairly new to regex in general. Basically I am trying to extract the name of a website from a text file.

myfile.txt example:

> Hello please enjoy your stay at%sbananas.com%sfor the rest of the day. Bye now!

I am trying to extract ***only*** the word bananas from this. My regex is as follows:

```
/(?<=m%s)(.*?)(?=\.com)/
```

Using regexr online it works just fine but in GREP code I just can't figure out how to get this to work properly. It doesn't return any results. I have tried several variants of the following:

```
grep "/(?<=m%s)(.*?)(?=\.com)/" myfile.txt
grep -E "/(?<=m%s)(.*?)(?=\.com)/" myfile.txt
grep '/(?<=m%s)(.*?)(?=\.com)/' myfile.txt
grep "(?<=m%s)(.*?)(?=\.com)" myfile.txt
grep '(?<=m%s)(.*?)(?=\.com)' myfile.txt
```

Nothing seems to work. I would love if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: `grep -Po "(?<=%s)(.*?)(?=\.com)" myfile.txt`

Comment: @steffen Please make an answer. Ideally one which explains the code-only solution your provided.

Comment: "but my regex is correct" What makes you think so? Why do you think that a typo in your regex is impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087059/extract-value-from-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-using-grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with regular expressions in `grep` and other Unix tools is that they usually support one, two or three different kinds of regular expressions. These are:

- Basic regular expressions (BRE)
- Extended regular expressions (ERE or EREG)
- Perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE or PREG)

Your pattern is in PCRE syntax, therefore you need to identify your pattern as one (using `-P`). Note that I also removed the `m` between `=` and `%` (I don't know what that was supposed to do).

```
grep -Po "(?<=%s)(.*?)(?=\.com)" myfile.txt
```

With `-o`, you say you only want to print the matching part. My `grep` man page declares PCRE in `grep` as experimental so there probably might be cases where you'd get a segmentation fault or where the evaluation takes unusually much time.

Comment: And the difference of the deleted `m` in the lookbehind condition .... ? `(?<=m%s)` !=  `(?<=%s)`

Comment: I actually don't know what that `m` was supposed to do.

Comment: But you deleted it. Note that I totally agree wiht deleting it, because I do not see how a regex including it could ever match. But the fact that it is there is enough explanation for it not working and makes the whole question mostly off-topic as "not reproduceable/typo". Just mention it as necessarily deleted, even if it is only a typo.

Comment: Note, there is an alternative, using `\K`. I thought that would allow to make a regex without PCRE support, but it seems I was wrong. It does work (tested on regex101.com), but is also PCRE, according to https://riptutorial.com/regex/topic/1338/match-reset---k I am not going to make a separate answer for this. Feel free to add this info to your answer, to make it more complete.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I know (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52796549/845034). But I don't get the point here. There are always more solutions to problems. I guess, the OP just wanted to know, why is regex did not work.

Comment: Yes, that is why I did not create another answer. But I thought I let you know, since I mentioned it in a deleted comment. By the way, I tried to change from typo close-vote to duplicate. I am convinced that it is the right thing to do here, but I would be sorry for you loosing the reputation in case the question finally gets deleted.